# jpeg_read_image’ is not a member of ‘boost::gil’

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, jpeg, gil

I am trying to read a jpg file with boost::gil. I started with the following code snippets but I got stuck already.

```
    #include <iostream>  
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>

    #include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
    #include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_dynamic_io.hpp>


     
    void ReadAnImage( std::string fname ){
                                                            
        std::vector<std::vector<float> > points;           
        boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img;                      
        boost::gil::jpeg_read_image( fname , img );               
    }                          
                               
                               
    int main( void ){
    
            ReadAnImage( "pic.jpg" );
    
    }
```

When I try to compile this code with

> g++ -I ~/programs/cpp/boost/include/ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main

I get the following error

> MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv]+0x1a): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error' MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv]+0x3f): undefined reference to` jpeg_CreateDecompress'
> MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv]+0x61): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src' MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader4initEv]+0x76): undefined reference to` jpeg_read_header'
> /tmp/ccrGnMRc.o: In function `boost::gil::detail::jpeg_reader::~jpeg_reader()': MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_readerD2Ev[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_readerD5Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to` jpeg_destroy_decompress'
> /tmp/ccrGnMRc.o: In function `void boost::gil::detail::jpeg_reader::apply<boost::gil::image_view<boost::gil::memory_based_2d_locator<boost::gil::memory_based_step_iterator<boost::gil::pixel<unsigned char, boost::gil::layout<boost::mpl::ve ctor3<boost::gil::red_t, boost::gil::green_t, boost::gil::blue_t>, boost::mpl::range_c<int, 0, 3> > >*> > > >(boost::gil::image_view<boost::gil::memory_based_2d_locator<boost::gil::memory_based_step_iterator<boost::gil::pixel<unsigned cha r, boost::gil::layout<boost::mpl::vector3<boost::gil::red_t, boost::gil::green_t, boost::gil::blue_t>, boost::mpl::range_c<int, 0, 3> > >*> > > const&)': MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0ELi 3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0 ELi3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT_]+0x2e): undefined reference to` jpeg_start_decompress'
> MainNew.cpp:(.text.*ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0ELi
> 3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT*[*ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0
> ELi3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT*]+0x13e): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines' MainNew.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0ELi 3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost3gil6detail11jpeg_reader5applyINS0_10image_viewINS0_23memory_based_2d_locatorINS0_26memory_based_step_iteratorIPNS0_5pixelIhNS0_6layoutINS_3mpl7vector3INS0_5red_tENS0_7green_tENS0_6blue_tEEENS9_7range_cIiLi0 ELi3EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvRKT_]+0x1ad): undefined reference to` jpeg_finish_decompress'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Because according to the documentation
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/gil/doc/html/index.html
the jpeg_read_image should be included in boost::gil. Am I maybe missing another header file??
Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: The documentation you link to is rather antiquated. [Here's a link to the latest version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/gil/doc/html/index.html). I/O seems to have been made an [extension](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/gil/doc/html/io.html), with a much simplified API (a single `read_image` function handling all formats)

Comment: @Some programmer dude. Thank you for your hint. I tried adapting the code. But still I am not able to get it working

Comment: The compile command should be g++ -I ~/programs/cpp/boost/include/ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -ljpeg. Then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Boost v1.75** the function
`boost::gil::jpeg_read_image(...)`
is still available in this header `#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg/old.hpp>`.

The new equivalent API (I think from Boost.GIL v1.68) is

```
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg.hpp>
boost::gil::write_view();
```

to manage JPEG use `boost::gil::jpeg_tag()`.

Example:

```
boost::gil::write_view("out.jpg", img_view, boost::gil::jpeg_tag());
```